# What is the difference between id and index of an element of array?

Tags: arrays

What is the difference between **id** and **index** of an element of array?

Comment: it's unclear what you're talking about. Add language tags, and example code. Generally, index is an index (and that concept should be clear from an understanding of what an array is), and an ID is ... an ID?

Answer (score 2):

index is the location, for example:

`int[] array={20,56,34,67,98}`

So `20` is at index 0, `56` is at index 1, `34` is at index 2 and so on...

id is some unique identifier, depend on the context.